# sftp command to get/download .tar.gz file

Tags: terminal, osx, scp, sftp

I thought I was familiar with `sftp` commands in unix and upto my knowledge the command to used to download a `compressed` file from the server is

> sftp get filename.tar.gz

But when I tried this command the file gets emptied, I mean the file size is going 0 and I don't know why it happens. Is there any other command specifically for `.tar.gz` type of files. What is the procedure to get this compressed files. I'm using mac terminal.

Comment: Don't you have to include the server address? What is the exact command you typed?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I've entered into server using sftp command. sftp user[at]server and in the sftp terminal I used `> get filename.tar.gz`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`get` is a legal sftp command, but can't be used that way.

The correct syntax to download `filename.tar.gz` to your Mac is:

```
sftp user@host:/path/to/filename.tar.gz /some/local/folder
```

(Replace `user` with the user you use to connect to the remote server, replace `host` with the remote server name.)

There's nothing special to `tar.gz` files in the above command, it is generic to any extension.

To use `get` you have to enter interactive mode first:

1. Make a connection to the remote server:

   ```
   sftp user@host
   ```

   Wait until `>`, the sftp prompt, appears in a newline - you can now type your commands.
2. Change the remote path to `/path/to`:

   ```
   cd /path/to/
   ```
3. Change the local path to `/some/local/folder`:

   ```
   lcd /some/local/folder
   ```
4. Use `get` to download the file:

   ```
   get filename.tar.gz
   ```

Comment: No, its not working I tried your suggestions. tried changing the local paths but no effect.

Comment: Could you post the output of the sftp command?

Comment: There is no such output kind of thing, as type `sftp > get filename.tar.gz` the file doesn't gets downloaded and the memory turns to be 0.

Comment: Neither `sftp > get filename.tar.gz` nor, as posted in your question, `sftp get filename.tar.gz` will work. The correct syntax is `sftp user@host:/path/to/filename.tar.gz /some/local/folder`, as explained in my answer. What happens when you type the command (replace `user`, `host`, `/path/to` and `/some/local/folder` with values that are correct in your environment) in Terminal and then press Enter? Is there any output? If so, please add it to our question.

Comment: There is NO output. it just goes to next line.

Comment: this is working

Answer (score 3):

Here another way if you are already logged into the the sftp session.

If you do a get:

```
sftp> get my-file.txt
get: failed to download /home/user/my-file.txt. Access is denied.
```

You may considere if locally you have the permissions to write. To check where the file will be downloaded do:

```
sftp> lpwd
C:\Users\user1\Documents
```

Generally "Documents" is not permissive. So, change the download dir to `C:\tmp`:

```
sftp> lcd C:\tmp
sftp> get my-file.txt
    Downloading my-file.txt from /home/user/my-file.txt
    1% 437123KB    620KB/s 00:00:41 ETA
```

Done